# EmberJs ember-data with ember-localstorage-adapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, adapter

Im using REST adapter by ember-data and it works fine. But now I want to use local storage for user settings storing.

Please, explain me, what is the right way?

I'm using ember-cli.

Comment: Do you mean the HTML5 local storage on the PC? If so, you need to be careful what user settings you save there as it it is completely open text data, available to any adverse parties who manage to get onto your machine. So no storing passwords, for instance.

Comment: Yes, I need it to save what tab was opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is create a file in the adapters folder, **with the same name of your model**

```
//app/adapters/settings.js
import LSAdapter from "your_adapter"
export default LSAdapter.extend();
```

For local storage you can use [Local Forage Adapter](https://github.com/genkgo/ember-localforage-adapter)

Comment: Now I'm on the way, but I'll try a bit more later. Thank u a lot! Could u tell me where I can get this information without stackoverflow? I just don't want to ask a lot of questions a day..

Comment: Well, the ember guides are pretty good if you are new to ember. Take a look in the adapters guide: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/customizing-adapters/.
As for ember-cli you should look in the ember-cli-guides: http://www.ember-cli.com/#naming-conventions

Comment: It seems I've missed that part, thk u again!